# Unable to connect Onvif camera

Tags: c#, camera, onvif

I have been working on ONVIF for a week. I want to  implement all the services provided by the ONVIF. I have managed to discover ONVIF devices and get information about the devices(like device's name, profiles, Uri ). I am using Onvif(discovery, services, session, utils) and utils( async, common, diagnostic ,utils.fsharp) as a project in my code.

I have two Cameras One is ReadLeaf and other is IPNC. I am able to discover both of them successfully. And when i am trying  to get information about the devices i am able to get information of the ReadLeaf camera correctly but in case of IPNC it is giving me  a error:-

**'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in
mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.**

> Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
>   authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received
>   from the server was 'Digest realm="onvif", qop="auth,auth-int",
>   nonce="587343b5ca703a95f874", opaque="08138641"'.

I googled this error and find that there could be two possible problems:

1) Mismatch between security settings on client and server.

2) This  usually happens because the message is sending a timestamp to Web log server and the response is coming with no timestamp, try turning off the timestamp in the security.

And then i have chat with my senior who told me that there is problem in the onvif implementation on the camera side. Camera manufacturer didn't  implement the onvif correctly into their camera.

Now, I am little bit confused that what is the exact problem here and what's the solution for the problem.

**Camera Details**:-

ReadLeaf Model -  RLC-DF2011

IPNC Model -   ONVIF_IPNC

Any kind of help will be  highly appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: If I were you I would try it with a standard onvif tool to see if it is really camera problem or your code. Example onvif tool: [ONVIF Device Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/)

Comment: If I remember right (haven't worked on ONVIF in like 3 years), the datetime of the camera has to match that of the machine communicating  with it. I could be wrong though, like I said it's been a while since I was involved in security. I remember having issues with DateTime's though

Comment: @user3060520 I have used onvif device manager tool and there also i am getting same error while  connecting  to the IPNC camera.

Comment: Did the IPNC camera come with any utilities that perform same operation(s)?Normally the best way of debugging these issues is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.Compare the messages in the working application with your c# code.Usually these error are due to the HTTP request missing required headers (or the headers have wrong options).  There a lots of reasons this could be occurring.Often Proxy servers or certificates are required, but it could just be a missing settings.Normally when debugging these issues I often delete the IE cookies after changing code.Pld cookie can cause errors.

Comment: @CallumBradbury, I have sync the timing of camera and my computer but it didn't work.

Comment: @jdweng you were right, there is problem in the HTTP request. But can you tell me how to correct  the format of its HTTP request.

Comment: You have to add (or not add) headers.  It depends on the header the method to add.  Some headers are standard and the Net Library has different format for adding that non standard headers.  Need to know which one.  An http connection may have multiple request/response to you have to get them working in order. Also if a cookie exist the headers will look different.  I always recommend remove cookies, modify code test.  Then repeat until you get it to work starting with cookies removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera implements the optional HTTP digest authentication. When a profile S camera implements both UsernameToken and HTTP digest authentication, the latter has to be proposed to the client if no authentication is provided.

The error that you see is probably because you are invoking an ONVIF function that requires authentication without providing credentials, thus the camera returns HTTP 401.

Just repeat the call by adding the crediantials for HTTP digest authentication. And be prepared to receive a soap error instead a HTTP 401 if you'll use a camera that does not implement digest.